# Let $f$ be differentiable $\exists\theta\backepsilon f(x+y)-f(x)=f '(x+\theta y)\cdot y$ Show that $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\theta=\dfrac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and such that $f''(x)\neq 0$.

Then $\phi(\tau)=f(x+\tau y):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $\phi '(\tau)=f'(x+\tau y)\cdot y,$ $y\neq0$.

By the MVT

$\exists\theta(x,y)=\theta\in[0,1]\backepsilon\phi(1)-\phi(0)=\phi '(\theta)$, which is unique if $y$ is "close enough" of $x$ since $f ''(0)\neq 0$.

Then

$f(x+y)-f(x)=f '(x+\theta y)\cdot y$

And what I want to show is $$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow 0}\theta(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

I was working on a problem and I found this interesting result, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Note that in many cases $\theta$ is not unique, so not well defined. Also, if it is not unique, choices of $\theta$ can lead to different limits... For example, take $f$ to be a constant function....

Comment: Then I think I can add the condition $f''(x)\neq 0$, so then $f'(x)$ should be monic in a neighborhood of $x$ so I can find a unique $\theta$

Comment: I don't think so. Assuming $f'' > 0$ would do what you say here...

Comment: I don't think any requirement on $f''$ is needed. My answer shows that $f(x+y)-f(x)=f '(x+\theta y)\cdot y$ as $y \to 0$ implies $\theta = 1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have
$f(x+y)-f(x)
=f '(x+\theta y)\cdot y
$,
this makes me think of
the more accurate derivative approximation
$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
=f'(x)+O(h^2f'''(x))
$.

Write it as
$\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}
=f '(x+\theta y)
$.
The right side is
$f'(x)+\theta y f''(x) + O(y^2)
$.
The left side is,
centering at $x+y/2$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{f(x+y/2+y/2)-f(x+y/2-y/2)}{y}
&=f'(x+y/2)+O(y^2)\\
&=f'(x)+(y/2)f''(x)+O(y^2)\\
\end{array}
$

These match only when
$f'(x)+\theta y f''(x) + O(y^2)
=f'(x)+(y/2)f''(x)+O(y^2)
$
which, as $y \to 0$,
requires
$\theta = \frac12$.